# react-export-excel how to hide column in excel when exported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

Hi I hope the title is enough to understand my problem. There is no error when exporting data, I just want that if the checkbox is unchecked or false it will hide the excel column of excel when exported. And if the checkbox is checked or true it will display or show the excel column when the excel is exported.

```
const [filteredData, setfilteredData] = useState(false)
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
const handleDisplay = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.checked)
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
}
....,

<Checkbox checked={checked} onChange={handleDisplay}  /> Display Name<br></br>

 <ExcelExported exportClass={'admin-add-btn'} filteredData={filteredData} checked={checked}></ExcelExported>
```

ExcelExported.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactExport from 'react-export-excel'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'



const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

function ExcelExported(props) {

    const { exportClass, filteredData, checked } = props
    console.log(checked)
    const fileNameFormatted = 'Student Information'
    return (
        <div>
            <ExcelFile filename="Student Information" element={
                <Button style={{ textTransform: 'none', minWidth: '240px' }}
                    className={exportClass}
                    variant='contained'
                // onClick={handlePrint}
                >
                    Export
                </Button>
            }>
                <ExcelSheet data={filteredData} name="Users" >
                    <ExcelColumn label="Student Name" value="name"  hide={checked}/>
                </ExcelSheet>
            </ExcelFile>

        </div >
    )
}

export default ExcelExported
```

this is my https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-excel library for exporting excel sheet

what i've tried so far is putting `hide={checked}` there is no error but even the checkbox is unchecked, it display the column, and i also tried this

```
{checked ? (<ExcelColumn label="Student Name" value="name")/>:(null)}
```

and i received this error

[image]

Comment: One thing to note is that on this line : `{checked ? (<ExcelColumn label="Student Name" value="name"):(null)}` it seems like you are not closing the `<ExcelColumn` tag anywhere ( you are missing the `/>` after `value="name"` ) . Also if that isn't the issue, maybe you could edit an existing sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/s/wrdew to give a minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: Sorry, its typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you pass in `null` as a child component of `ExcelFile`.

Let's locate the (approximate) line the stacktrace is showing in `react-export-excel`'s source. It loops over all children of that component and will always [try to access the `props` property of them](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/5ede0a82492563f9219ba8d53cda406c22811347/src/ExcelPlugin/components/ExcelFile.js#L55).

```
// src/ExcelPlugin/components/ExcelFile.js

const columns = sheet.props.children;
const sheetData = [
  React.Children.map(columns, column => column.props.label)
];
```

So this component will only ever work (i.e. not crash) if all of its children are objects with this expected structure.

You'll get the same error with `checked && <ExcelColumn/>`, where it receives `false` as a child. In a regular React component both `null` and `false` are "ignored" (they don't have output). But because this component loops over it with `React.children`, it just gets the exact list you put into it.

Further down the code it looks like it also has no way to prevent a column from being included. You can try passing in other things, but it's likely still going to be included as an extra comma separate column.

Perhaps this could be facilitated by this library by ignoring these values too. It could get tricky, though. As the amount of columns always needs to match the data. So it's understandable that this component does not provide this level of flexibility at the moment.

### Alternative

Instead of using `<ExcelColumn/>` components, you can define the columns in the `dataSet` object. An [example from their documentation](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/08acfd8411dab1d14eedd885eadd572fbbe53e67/examples/simple_excel_export_02.md):

```
const multiDataSet = [
  {
    columns: [
      { value: "Name", widthPx: 50 }, // width in pixels
      { value: "Salary", widthCh: 20 }, // width in charachters
    ],
    data: [
      // ...
    ],
  },
  // ...
];

// ...
<ExcelSheet dataSet={multiDataSet} name="Organization"/>
```

This way you have direct control over the `columns` list and can filter it depending on certain hook values.

You'll also have to guarantee the rows have the same filters applied.

Here's a quick example implementation showing how to manage the state of the hidden rows. This could be done completely different depending on your use case / existing state management solution.

```
const allColumns = [{value: "columnA"}, {value: "columnB"} /* ... */];
const [hiddenColumns, setHiddenColumns] = useState({});
const isVisible = col => !hiddenColumns[col.name];
const toggleColumn = col => setHiddenColumns({
  ...hiddenColumns,
  [col.name]: !hiddenColumns[col.name],
})

// Get indexes of hidden columns to hide them in data too.
const hiddenIndexes = Object.entries(hiddenColumns).filter(([,hidden]) => hidden).map(
  ([hiddenCol]) => allColumns.findIndex(column => column.value === hiddenCol)
)
const dataSet = {
  // ...
  columns: allColumns.filter(isVisible);
  data: rows.map(
    cells => cells.filter(
      (cell, index) => !hiddenIndexes.includes(index)
    )
  ),
}

return <Fragment>
  <ExcelFile><ExcelSheet {...{dataSet}}/></ExcelFile>
  {allColumns.map(
    col => 
      <Checkbox
        checked={!isVisible(col)}
        onChange={()=> toggleColumn(col.name)}
      >
        col.value
      </Checkbox>
  )}
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
{checked && <ExcelColumn label="Student Name" value="name"/>}
```

Comment: I've already done that, and I received error just like in my post

Comment: I think error occurs because <ExcelSheet/> has not a single <ExcelColumn/> as a child.

Comment: If you had more than one column issue did not occur in the first place.
One thing you can try is applying condition on <ExcelSheet/> instead of  <ExcelColumn/>

Comment: This will have the same problem, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73762405/4961158).